# How to show one documents (resource) information (pagetitle and TV's) with different templates?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have two external links and I need to show information from document (pagetitle and TV's) with two different templates (standard, print mode). IS there any solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Symlinks for this resource with needed templates. https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/symlink/using-resource-symlinks

**UPD:**

```
<?php
$from_parent_id = 8; // Test 1 dir id
$to_parent_id = 9; // Test2 dir id
$to_template_id = 2; // Template id of newly created symlink

if ($modx->event->name == 'OnDocFormSave') {
    if ( $mode == modSystemEvent::MODE_NEW ) {
        $parent = $resource->get('parent');
        if ($from_parent_id == $parent) {
            $fields = array(
                'template' => $to_template_id,
                'content_type' => 1,
                'class_key' => 'modSymLink',
                'context_key' => 'web',
                'parent' => $to_parent_id,
                'richtext' => 0,
                'hidemenu' => 0,
                'published' => 1,
                'searchable' => 0,
                'cacheable' => 1,
                'content' => $id,
            );
            $new_resource = $modx->newObject('modSymlink', $fields);
            $new_resource->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vasis, I've seen this solution. Is there any solution how to make automatically new symlink in special folder (actually few symlinks in few folders) after creating new resource?

Comment: To do this you need to create custom plugin on `OnDocFormSave` event.

Comment: do you you know any examples or tutorials how it works? I'm bad in php :(

Comment: For example: after creating new document with name "000000001" in folder Test1 I need automatically to create document (symlink) with the same pagetitle, longtitle and alias, but with another template "templateExample" in folder Test2 with id of first document.

Comment: thanks, Vasis for your help, just tried your code. it works great!!! how to add the same longtitle, pagetitle, and alias of resource and how to make 2 (or even 3) symlinks in different folders?

Comment: it works great!!! 
I've added two lines, or doesn't make sens
` 'pagetitle' => $resource->get('pagetitle'),
'alias' => $resource->get('pagetitle'),   '`

Comment: Alias would be `'alias' => $resource->get('alias')` or empty.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the MODX extra [SwitchTemplate](http://modx.com/extras/package/switchtemplate) is an option for your demand?

This extra changes the MODX resource template on the fly by an request parameter. It could be installed by Package Management in MODX backend.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Have extended the answer. The link is a permalink.